# Cypress : Still waiting to connect to Chrome, retrying in 1 second

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, cypress

Im trying to run cypress but i have this error message "Still waiting to connect to Chrome, retrying in 1 second"
Cypress version 9.5.3
Chrome version 99.0.4844.84
MacsOs : Big sur
[image]

Comment: Got this error with Chrome 117, had to upgrade Cypress to the latest version to fix it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Solved by closing another instance of chrome browser that I did not notice was running in the background

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and closed my other Chrome window which had 4 tabs open, and the tests started working.